# perl script . try to force a suffix to the name of created files

Tags: perl

I received a number of answers to my previous question (thank you everyone who responded) the most appropriate being -

```
perl -ne 'BEGIN{$/ = \2769} print {open $f, ">",  ++$i; $f } $_' $DATAPATH/data/TRI001MSX.
```

This creates a number of datasets named 1,2,3,4,5...n.

I would like it to create files with a suffix, for instance x1,x2,x3,x4...xn.

Any assistance gratefully accepted.

Comment: Replace `++$i` with `"x" . ++$i`, or with `"x$."`.

Comment: The perl instructions given worked perfectly.

Comment: The perl instructions worked perfectly. Thank you to all who responded. Bernie

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the examples at the start of the [`open()` documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html), you will see that the filename is the third argument to `open()`.

Currently this is simply an incrementing number (`++$x`). To change this so that your filenames have a fixed prefix, it is just a case of concatenating your fixed string with your incrementing number. Perl's concatenation operator is a dot (`.`).

So your `open()` call would become:

```
open $f, ">",  'X' . ++$i;
```

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, then please consider voting it up or accepting it.